# English translation of Serre's paper Gèbres

Tags: reference-request, translation

Does anyone know if it is possible to find an English translation of Serre's paper [Gèbres](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-60413)?

Here is the complete reference:

Serre, Jean-Pierre. Gèbres. (French) [Gebras] Enseign. Math. (2) 39 (1993), no. 1-2, 33--85. [MR1225256](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1225256) (94h:16074)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "gèbres" has nothing to do with "gerbes". I've therefore removed the tag you just added.

Comment: @YCor I thought it is french name for gerbes :D apologies.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "gerbes" is a French word, literally used in mathematical English. "gèbres" is a truncation of "algèbres", which is the French translation of "algebra", so is "gebra" in English by obvious analogy.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the clarification :) @YCor