# Paper, open source English translation

Tags: math-communication, translation

Please suggest a paper that should be translated into English and posted on arXiv.

A few existing suggestions on MO are

- [Die 5-fach transitiven Gruppen von Mathieu, Witt](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196670/) ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02948947))
- [Die Monodromie der Isolierten Singularitäten von Hyperflächen, Brieskorn](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229609/)
- [Gèbres, Serre](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84803/)

I propose to have the translation done in an open source fashion, for example [like this](https://www.overleaf.com/5792478ccrmwj) (switch to *source mode* on the upper left).

[Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17778/) on books. 
[Related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27892/does-translating-an-article-for-a-magazine-require-permission-from-the-author) on copyright.

Comment: Is it legal to publish a translation of a copyrighted work?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: There are examples on arXiv linked in the comments [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/196676/56620). But this issue deserves a separate question, and should probably be addressed on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Generally, no, not without the permission of the copyright holder (author and/or journal).

Comment: But I would think in many cases translation rights would be gladly granted if you ask.

Comment: I think the crucial issue here is payment -- honorary for the translator and a fee for the rights to the copyright holder (the latter unless permission is granted for free, of course). How do you propose to arrange these payments?

Comment: Witt's paper was published in 1937. A copyright typically expires after 70 years, so I don't see how it can still be under copyright.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: The 70 years are correct for many countries -- but 70 years after the author's death, and not after publication. In the given case, the author [Ernst Witt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Witt) died in 1991, thus for copyright expiration you would probably need to wait until 2061.

Comment: @StefanKohl : do you mean that Witt held the copyright, and not the journal?

Comment: I submitted a request for permission to publish a translation. As soon as I get a quote I will post it here.

Comment: I received a quote, for 2,036.29 £, from Copyright Clearance Center, which does these clearances for Springer publications. I guess I will pass on this one :-)

Answer (score 3):

I submitted a request for permission to publish a translation of the Witt's article. As soon as I get a quote I will post it here.

Comment: I received a quote, for 2,036.29 £, from  Copyright Clearance Center, which does these clearances for Springer publications. I guess I will pass on this one :-)